How to start SikuliX script in Robot Framwork?
I'm having trouble getting the SikuliX script to work in Robot Framework. Is there any more convenient method? I created the script in the SikuliX IDE, then exported it as a runnable jar, and then used the “Run Process” keyword in Robot Framework. For example:
Run Process    java    -jar    /home/user/Projects/SikuliX/TestCases_sikuli.jar

Here: How to run sikuli script inside robot framework? I found the following information written by Rainman: "If you use sikuli IDE, and saved your test case as sikuli script. You could execute the sikuli scripts in RobotFramework test cases.". I don't know how to do it, how to start *.sikuli in Robot Framework. Can anyone help?
